# iOS Push Notification, automatically response to server when received message

Tags: ios, background, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My request is to send push notification from Server to iPhone. Everything is working well. Unless I need my iPhone side to be able to feedback to server side when receive notification immediately. If my app is foreground, I can send HTTP request via **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method. But if my app is in background (click home button to exit), **didReceiveRemoteNotification** is not called at all! Why??? I'm pulling my hair!

Technically i believe it's realizable. I check the "Whats App", phoneA sends message to phoneB: if phoneB is offline, phoneA only gets a single tick. Later if phoneB get on line, phoneA will get a double ticks. And if phoneB is in background, phoneA also can get a double tick. Which means although phoneB is in background, but it did something.

I'm wondering how Whats App can do when the app is in background.

Thanks a lot!
Regards,

Benroo

Comment: you can run your app in the background for 10 minutes after you exit the app

Comment: Not exactly, once I exit the app, didReceiveRemoteNotification will not be called at all. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the screen shot and figure it out you did the same in ur app to get call the didReceiveRemoteNotification while your app in background[image]